# JavaScript Constants - pass as argument or use directly?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'm wondering what the best practice is regarding using declared constants in JavaScript. Is it better to pass the constant as an argument to the function or is it better to use the constant without passing?

My instinct is to not pass the constant as an argument because that produces an unnecessary local copy of the variable.  However, it might be more clear where the constant is coming from if it is passed.

```
const myConstant = 1;

myFunc();
myOtherFunc(myConstant);

/* use constant without passing */
function myFunc() {
   console.log(`${myConstant} is a constant`);
}

/* pass constant as argument */
function myOtherFunc(localCopy) {
   console.log(`${localCopy} is a constant`);
}
```

Comment: Well, do you need `myFunc(someThingElseThan1)` or not? Don't declare it as a parameter when it is not, don't pass it as an argument if it's always the same.

Comment: "*it might be more clear where the constant is coming from if it is passed*" - where is that clear? I don't see how `localCopy` is a constant at all.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. If it is expected not to change, don't pass as an argument.

Answer (score 1):

There are tradeoffs going in both directions, though most of them are in the area of unit testing and re-usability.

The more you hard code things, the less flexibility you have in testing.

Let me give what a contrived example:

```
const FIRST_NAME_MAX_LEN = 20;
```

And, in our validation code, we look at that constant and compare it to the length of the input field...

```
function validateFirstName() {
  return document.getElementsByName("first-name")[0].length <= FIRST_NAME_MAX_LEN;
}
```

Ok, this works, but we have no way to test that validateFirstName() works without invoking the entire DOM.  it is harder to test.

On the other hand, if we create a function like:

```
function validateStringLength(s, maxLength) {
    return s.length <= maxLength;
}
```

then we've created a function that takes passed parameters, is re-usable in other places and very easily tested in any testing framework.  DOM not required.

By relying upon the constant, you have created a `dependency` on that value and where it live.  Research `JavaScript Dependency Injection` for much more on this topic.